# jMockit - How make constructor invocation to return a mock

Tags: java, mocking, testng, jmockit

We are currently using Mockito + PowerMock as our main mocking framework and had a few issues with this once started moving some of our code to java 8.
Because of this we decided to evaluate jMockit as an alternative. I have quite a good understanding of mocking concepts but I admit that my experience with jMockit is very limited.

However I am having problems with testing something that in my view should be very basic: the class under test creates an instance of some other class inside its constructor using new. That new invocation is the thing that I would like to make return a mock instance.

Here is the code like the one I am using:
    package com.some.org.some.app;

```
import mockit.Expectations;
import mockit.Injectable;
import mockit.Mocked;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ClassUnderTestTest {
    interface SomeService {
        void doWork();
    }

    class ClassUnderTest {
        private final SomeService service;

        public ClassUnderTest() {
            this.service = new SomeService() {
                @Override
                public void doWork() {
                }
            };
        }
    }

    @Injectable
    private SomeService mockService;

    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToMaskVariousNumbers() throws Exception {
        new Expectations() {{
            new ClassUnderTest();
            result = mockService;
        }};
    }
}
```

When running the above I am getting the exception below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing invocation to mocked type at this point;
please make sure such invocations appear only after the declaration of a suitable
mock field or parameter
```

I am using TestNG as a testing framework and in reality my test method has a bunch of parameters as it is expecting some test data being passed by a data provider.

This is pretty basic and it looks like my approach is not the jMockit way. Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very easy to do with JMockit:

```
public class ClassUnderTestTest {
    interface SomeService { int doWork(); }

    class ClassUnderTest {
        private final SomeService service;

        ClassUnderTest() {
            service = new SomeService() {
                @Override public int doWork() { return -1; }
            };
        }

        int useTheService() { return service.doWork(); }
    }

    // This annotation is a variation on @Mocked, which extends
    // mocking to any implementation classes or subclasses of
    // the mocked base type.
    @Capturing SomeService mockService;

    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToMaskVariousNumbers() {
        new Expectations() {{ mockService.doWork(); result = 123; }};

        int n = new ClassUnderTest().useTheService();

        assertEquals(123, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was very easy indeed. Thank you very much for your inputs. I also learn the correct usage of the Capturing annotation. When I read the tutorial I haven’t paid much attention to this in the first place as I thought it may be used for capturing invocation data such as method parameters, etc. It seems to me I need to have another, this time more carefully, read  of the jMockit tutorial. 
As for the exception I was getting, my silly mistake was I was setting an expectation on the ClassUnderTest constructor which was obviously wrong.